# Code Igniter form not posting

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have made a site in CodeIgniter2, but I can't get the forms to work, as I can't seem to even work out how to get it to post! Any help? Here is my code and the forms are only on the recommend, contact-us and support pages:

Form:

```
<div id="mainWhiteBox">
        <h3>Tell people about us...</h3>
        <p>If you know of a company or individual who need a really great design agency to help them with a project, let them know about us and benefit too. <br /><br />
        <span class="customColour">We will give you &pound;50 of Marks &amp; Spencer vouchers for every client you recommend to us who goes on to become a client of xxxxx, it's that simple &amp; there is no limit to the amount of vouchers you can earn!</span></p>
        <div id="recommendSomeone">
            <?php echo validation_errors(); print_r($_POST);?>
            <?php echo form_open('recommend', array('id' => 'recommendForm')); ?>
                <label for="friendName">Your Friend's Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="friendName" value="<?php echo set_value('friendName'); ?>" />
                <label for="friendEmail">Your Friend's Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" id="friendEmail" value="<?php echo set_value('friendEmail'); ?>" placeholder="someone@youknow.com" />
                <label for="customerName">Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="customerName" value="<?php echo set_value('customerName'); ?>" />
                <label for="customerEmail">Your Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" id="customerEmail" value="<?php echo set_value('customerEmail'); ?>" placeholder="you@youremailaddress.com" />
                <label for="friendConfirm"><input type="checkbox" id="friendConfirm" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('friendConfirm', '1'); ?> />I confirm that I know the person I am recommending above.</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Recommendation" />
            </form>
            <img src="<?=base_url(); ?>images/uploads/<?php echo $images[0]["image_filename"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[0]["image_alt"]; ?>" width="180px" height="300px" class="floatRight" />
        </div>
        <p class="elevenFont">* Get &pound;50 of Marks &amp; Spencer vouchers per company or person recommended who goes on to open an account with xxxxx.</p>
    </div>
    <?php include("/home/xxxxx/libraries/application/views/widgets/newsWidget.php"); ?>
    <?php include("/home/xxxxx/libraries/application/views/widgets/twitterWidget.php"); ?>
    <?php include("/home/xxxxx/libraries/application/views/widgets/quickViewWidget.php"); ?>
    <?php include("/home/xxxxx/libraries/application/views/widgets/fbLikePageWidget.php"); ?>
    <?php include("/home/xxxxx/libraries/application/views/widgets/getQuoteBarWidget.php"); ?>
    <?php include("/home/xxxxx/libraries/application/views/widgets/newsletterSubscribeWidget.php"); ?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('pages_model');
}


public function view($page = 'home')
{

    if ( ! file_exists('/home/urbanfea/libraries/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }       

    $data['title'] = $this->pages_model->getTitle($page);
    $data['showcase'] = $this->pages_model->getShowcase();
    $data['news'] = $this->pages_model->getNewsWidgetContent();
    $data['quote'] = $this->pages_model->getQuoteFromBank();
    $data['images'] = $this->pages_model->getPageImageArray($page);
    $data['PageStraplines'] = $this->pages_model->getStraplines($page);
    $data['serverStatus'] = $this->pages_model->getIssue("1");

    if($page == "support")
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/supportHead', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/head', $data); 
    }

    if($page == "recommend" || $page == "contact-us" || $page == "support")
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('friendName', 'Friend\'s Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('friendEmail', 'Friend\'s Email Address', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customerName', 'Customer\'s Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customerEmail', 'Customer\'s Email Address', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules(FriendConfirm', 'Confirm you know the person', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/formSuccess', $data); echo "a";
        }
        elseif($this->form_validation->run() === false && validation_errors() != "")
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/formError', $data); echo "b";
        }
        elseif($this->form_validation->run() === false)
        {
            echo "c";
        }

    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
```

}

?>

**Edit**

Here are the routes in my router:

```
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['user/(:any)'] = 'user/view/$1';
$route['user'] = 'user/login';
$route['our-work/(:any)'] = 'our_work/view/$1';
$route['our-work'] = 'our_work';
$route['what-we-do/(:any)'] = 'what_we_do/view/$1';
$route['what-we-do'] = 'what_we_do';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form_open function `echo form_open('recommend', array('id' => 'recommendForm'));` will create the following output: `<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/recommend" />`

This is looking for a controller called recommend, which I don't think is what you want. Change the form_open function so it directs your form to the proper controller/action.

Also, it doesn't look like your code is taking full advantage of the MVC framework. Instead of handling passing everything through the same controller/function and having all those if statements to load different views based on what $page is, you should have separate functions for each of those views.

**EDIT:**
Your form input elements are missing the `name` attribute. They must have the name attribute to be accessible through $_POST. Take a look at [this page in the Codeigniter help](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html). Maybe make use of the form_input function to generate the input fields?

Comment: Hi AndrewR, It is my first MVC site, I have been programatically coding up to now so the MVC code is new to me, so that's why I didn't make a different view. No I don't want it to go to a recommend controller, it is sent to the pages controller. I'm confused because it will 'refresh' the page and echo the c to show that no form has been submitted (in the if underneath where I set the rules), but `print_r($_POST);` just shows an empty array :S

Comment: You're not doing some kind of redirect in your routes.php file to get everything to the same Pages/View controller are you?

Comment: You're missing the `name` attribute on your form inputs. See updated answer.

Comment: if adding the name attribute doesn't fix it for you, could you explain how you saw the redirect or were you just assuming one.  If you saw it through the network tab of chrome as a 302 its a similiar problem I've ran into that will make you slap your head.

Comment: Please see my edited answer for my routes.php file, All static pages go through pages/view. I think I'll make a seperate function for the form pages too. Thanks for the `name` spot as well, that has solved my problem :)

Comment: Great it's solved. :) Your routes.php looks fine. @John B was thinking the same thing I was at first. If you did a 302 redirect from routes.php, that would strip out your form variables.